Rakuten RMS Product API ジャンルID (Genre ID)
I am trying to develop a system that will be able to push my products on Rakuten online marketplace in Japan with their API.
Their API for that is named Product API, or more recently Item API 2.0.
The major issue I am facing with this is the required field ジャンルID or "Genre ID" in English.
Basically I have to specify, for each one of my products, to which genre it belongs. Moreover, each genre will have different attributes (for example T-shirt genre can have Color and Material), and each attribute will have default values (blue, black, etc.) that I also have to specify.
However, Rakuten does not provide any tool to help that. I was wondering if anyone already had to deal with this Rakuten API.
Any idea of how to solve this so that we don't have to manually specify every values for each product in a big database?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
